# Is it possible to have an if inside an if in return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering if it's possible to have an if statement inside an if statement in a return.

I am aware of the following syntax:

```
return (
  <div>
    { myVar ? <Component/> : <AnotherComponent/> }
  </div>
)
```

What I want is something like this:

```
return (
<div id="App">
  { loading ? 
    <Loading/>
      :
      userIsLoggedIn ?
        <Redirect to="/login"/>
          :
        <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>      
  }
</div>
)
```

Is this possible? If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You _can_, but I'd recommend you _don't_ - chaining ternary expressions isn't a recipe for readability.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So, what would you recommend then?

Comment: Early return from the render method/component function, extract sub-components, use higher-order components, ...

Comment: Sometimes an if statement can help too: `if (isLoggedIn) { return <UserGreeting />; } return <GuestGreeting />;` from the docs: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a bad practice, avoid nested ternary... but your code will be like this:

```js
return (
  <div id="App">
    { loading ? <Loading/> : (userIsLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/login"/> :<Redirect to="/dashboard"/>)}
  </div>
);
```